# Возможно ли создать полноценный аналог Uber используя его открытый api?

Tags: android, api

Предоставляет ли Uber весь функционал в своих апи , поделитесь опытом те кому довелось поработать .

Comment: если в приложении еще будет карта, то вы познакомитесь с чудесным миром ограничений гугл карт

Answer (score 3):

[Android API Uber](https://developer.uber.com/docs/riders/ride-requests/tutorials/api/android) дает возможность только заказать поездку, при этом с ограничением:

> This endpoint requires a privileged scope to be used in production by all Uber riders. You can use this endpoint immediately when authenticated as yourself or any of your 5 registered developers. When you are ready to distribute your application broadly for use by all Uber riders, you may request FULL ACCESS. For more information read about scopes.

То есть чтобы ваше приложение могло рассылать приглашение всем водителям Uber, вы должны получить некие привилегии. Что-то смутно мне подсказывает, что получить такие привилегии будет крайне сложно :)